# embed responsive youtube videos in a grid

Tags: bootstrap-5

I try to display some youtube videos inside a grid. I cant figure out how to make them responsible. They appear very small on a larger screen and the size doesnt change.

there shoudl be 2 videos next to each other on larger screens and an smaller screens they should stack up

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 g-4">
          <div class="col justify-content-center">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
              <iframe
                class="embed-responsive-item"
                src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Video1"
              ></iframe>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col justify-content-center">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
              <iframe
                class="embed-responsive-item"
                src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Video2"
              ></iframe>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Add more rows and columns for additional videos -->
        </div>
        <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 g-4">
          <div class="col justify-content-center">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
              <iframe
                class="embed-responsive-item"
                src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Video3"
              ></iframe>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col justify-content-center">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
              <iframe
                class="embed-responsive-item"
                src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Video3"
              ></iframe>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Add more rows and columns for additional videos -->
        </div>
      </div>
```

Tried different methods and CSS style, classes within Bootstrap5

Answer (score 0):

You can add class `w-100` this means what the video will be 100% of the container width.
Here is the code:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 g-4">
          <div class="col justify-content-center">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
              <iframe class="embed-responsive-item w-100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Video1" ></iframe>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col justify-content-center">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
              <iframe class="embed-responsive-item w-100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Video2" ></iframe>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Add more rows and columns for additional videos -->
        </div>
        <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 g-4">
          <div class="col justify-content-center">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
              <iframe class="embed-responsive-item w-100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Video3"></iframe>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col justify-content-center">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
              <iframe class="embed-responsive-item w-100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Video3"></iframe>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Add more rows and columns for additional videos -->
        </div>
      </div>
```